# Broken pipe error when using FFmpeg stream camera video

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, opencv, python

I try to write frames captured from a my laptop camera and then stream these images with FFmpeg. This is my code:

```
import subprocess
import cv2
rstp_url = "rtsp://localhost:31415/stream"

# In my mac webcamera is 0, also you can set a video file name instead, for example "/home/user/demo.mp4"
path = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)

# gather video info to ffmpeg
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

# command and params for ffmpeg
command = ['ffmpeg',
           '-y',
           '-f', 'rawvideo',
           '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
           '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
           '-s', "{}x{}".format(width, height),
           '-r', str(fps),
           '-i', '-',
           '-c:v', 'libx264',
           '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
           '-preset', 'ultrafast',
           '-f', 'flv',
           rstp_url]

# using subprocess and pipe to fetch frame data
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)


while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("frame read failed")
        break

    # YOUR CODE FOR PROCESSING FRAME HERE

    # write to pipe
    p.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())
```

After run this code, the following error occurs:

> Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:':
> Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 221184 kb/s
> Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[24] / 0x18524742), bgr24, 640x480, 221184 kb/s, 30 > tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
> rtsp://localhost:31415/stream: Protocol not found
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "rtsp.py", line 42, in 
> p.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())
> BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Please help me fix this bug.

---

After reply by Rotem, I modidied code as below:

```
import subprocess
import cv2
import pdb 

rstp_url = "rtsp://localhost:31415/stream"

# In my mac webcamera is 0, also you can set a video file name instead, for example "/home/user/demo.mp4"
path = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)

# gather video info to ffmpeg
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

# command and params for ffmpeg
command = ['ffmpeg',
           '-re',
           '-f', 'rawvideo',  # Apply raw video as input - it's more efficient than encoding each frame to PNG
           '-s', f'{width}x{height}',
           '-pixel_format', 'bgr24',
           '-r', f'{fps}',
           '-i', '-',
           '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
           '-c:v', 'libx264',
           '-bufsize', '64M',
           '-maxrate', '4M',
           '-rtsp_transport', 'udp',
           '-f', 'rtsp',
           #'-muxdelay', '0.1',
           rstp_url ]


# using subprocess and pipe to fetch frame data
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)


while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("frame read failed")
        break

    pdb.set_trace()
    # YOUR CODE FOR PROCESSING FRAME HERE

    # write to pipe
    p.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())

    cv2.imshow('current_img', frame)  # Show image for testing

    # time.sleep(1/FPS)
    key = cv2.waitKey(int(round(1000/fps)))  # We need to call cv2.waitKey after cv2.imshow

    if key == 27:  # Press Esc for exit
        break

p.stdin.close()  # Close stdin pipe
p.wait()  # Wait for FFmpeg sub-process to finish
cv2.destroyAllWindows()  # Close OpenCV window
```

The error ocurs as below:

> Connection to tcp://localhost:31415?timeout=0 failed: Connection >refused
> Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec >parameters ?): Connection refused
> Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
> Conversion failed!
> c
> Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols >specified are supported.

Comment: You may take a look at the self contained RTSP streaming [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68545688/stream-images-from-python-opencv-with-ffmpeg) that I have posted. It's not working when replacing `'-f', 'rtsp'` with `'-f', 'flv'`. It looks like RTSP protocol does not support FLV container, but I am not sure (Google results suggests that RTMP uses FLV container).

Comment: Hi, Rotem. Thank you for your reply. Your example works well for me, but if I delete code with respect to ffplay, the error as modified quetion as above occurs.